# SurfaceView rendering first before any other view

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a `SurfaceView` in my layout with other `views` in 1st `fragment` while navigating from one 1st`fragment` to 2nd `Fragment` the the `SurfaceView` getting invisible before any other `view` .while back from the 2nd fragment `SurfaceView` is rendering first before any other view in the layout of 1st `Fragment`.So basically here `SurfaceView` is `rendering` before any other `view`  so how to render it same time with the other `views` in the `Layout`.